# updating(copying) specific column values from tmp table to main table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

**tbl1**

```
id             int(11)      NOT NULL

userName       varchar(45)  NOT NULL

positionName   varchar(20)  NULL

positionId     int(11)      NULL
```

**tmpTbl1**

```
id             int(11)      NOT NULL

userName       varchar(45)  NOT NULL

positionName   varchar(20)  NULL

positionId     int(11)      NULL
```

In `tbl1`, only `id` and `userName` columns have data.  for `tmpTbl1`, all columns have data.

I want to copy `positionName` and `positionId` of `tmpTbl1` to `tbl1`.

Both tables have same structures and `id` and `userName` columns data are same too. Just want to update the left two columns data into `tbl1`.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested quickly - but I think this will work for you

```
UPDATE tbl1 t1, tmpTbl1 t2 
SET t1.positionName=t2.positionName, t1.positionId=t2.positionId 
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.userName=t2.userName;
```

Comment: thanks. It works. :) will accept the answer after the limit time . Thanks you so much.